# Vegetable similar to ivy gourd?

Tags: vegetables, fruit, indian-cuisine

I'm looking for the English name for a vegetable / fruit that looks like an Ivy Gourd. The taste is similar as well, but the texture is gritty. The Gujarati pronunciation is `puhr-ver`, but I have no idea what vegetable / fruit this is. Thank you.

Comment: Is that the Gujarati name for the thing you're asking about, or for ivy gourd? If it's the thing you're asking about, giving the actual Gujarati spelling might help you get answers.

Comment: Are you looking for gherkin?

Comment: @Escose Nope, a Pointed Gourd is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Here is the Wikipedia article on the gourd: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichosanthes_dioica

It is also known as the Pointed Gourd.